What is the Catholic view on the Old Testament custom of the firstborn son taking the place of the Father and being the head of the family?
I'm basically wondering from a natural law, biblical or whatever other perspective the Catholic Church's view on the matter. Is this practice still around, or does headship transfer to the wife.

Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  If you have not already done so, please take our Tour which explains how we are different from other sites. I hope this question will not be closed down.
